# How many 5-digit numbers can we assemble from the numbers 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 if the digits in each number can be repeated only once?

Tags: combinatorics

The wording here threw me off.

The answer given is $8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4$.

This suggests that "repeated once" means only used once. I interpreted "repeated once" to mean a digit $2,...,9$ can be used either once or twice (at most). Suppose I instead wish to answer the question that I interpreted it as. That is, I can use each digit once or twice but not more than twice.

I split this into 3 cases. The first is where no digit is repeated. The number of ways we can get this is $8 \cdot7 \cdot6 \cdot5 \cdot4 $.

Now suppose we have one repeat then we have $\left[\binom{5}{2} \cdot 8\right] \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$ ways. That is, we can choose two slots out of five to put the first digit in.

Now suppose we have two repeats then we have $\left[\binom{5}{2} \cdot 8\right] \cdot \left[\binom{3}{2} \cdot 7\right]\cdot 6$. That is, we can choose two slots out of five to put the first digit in. Then we have to choose two of the remaining three slots to put the next digit in.

In summing the cases we get the result. Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $\left[\binom{5}{2} \cdot 8\right] \cdot \left[\binom{3}{2} \cdot 7\right]\cdot 6$

The two repeated case is over counting, suppose the five seats are

$$\_~,~\_~,~\_~,~\_~,~\_~$$

First, you choose two seats, and fill in $2$

$$2~,~2~,~\_~,~\_~,~\_~$$

Next, you choose two seats, and fill in $3$

$$2~,~2~,~\_~,~3~,~3~$$

This is as the same as below:

First, you choose two seats, and fill in $3$

$$\_~,~\_~,~\_~,~3~,~3~$$

Next, you choose two seats, and fill in $2$

$$2~,~2~,~\_~,~3~,~3~$$

So you are over counting by twice.
$$===========\text{Therefore, the correct answer is:}===========$$

> $$8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4+\left[\binom{5}{2}\cdot8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot5\right]+\color{red}{\frac{1}2}\left[ \binom{5}{2}\cdot8\binom{3}{2}\cdot7\cdot6\right]=28560$$

Alternative method, no over counting risk, which is

"All cases" -" five repeated case" -" four repeated case"-" three repeated case"

> $$8^5-\binom{5}{5}\cdot8-\binom{5}{4}\cdot8\cdot 7-\binom{5}{3}\cdot8\cdot7^2=28560$$

Comment: I shall think about this. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: An alternative method you can consider is "all cases" -" three repeated" - "four repeated" - "five repeated". This is a "safe" method, because there is no over counting issues. @HMPtwo

Comment: There is no possibility of getting three (or four or five) repeated though?

Comment: -" three repeated" - "four repeated" - "five repeated" means to exclude these un-qualified cases, so subtract them from "all cases"

Comment: I add the alternative method to the answer. @HMPtwo

Comment: From your answer I thought the resolution would be to multiply the 5C2 3C2 term by half. But I can't justify it from scratch. Is it literally the case that "upon examination we can see that the 5C2 3C2  over counts by 2 so we multiply it by half"? Or can you "show" it with rigour (whatever that means)?

Comment: Concerning the alternative method, the last term counts terms such as 44455 is that correct? I would have thought it would be 5C3 x 8 x 7 x 6? Or does it mean "three repeated plus anything else"?

Comment: I meant to include you in those comments @MathFail

Comment: Yes, it counts cases such as $44455$, the two digits can be either repeated or not. @HMPtwo

Comment: Could you confirm or deny my comment on the derivation of the 0.5 in the 5C2 3C2 term? @MathFail

Comment: Sure, I just saw that comment, if you are not convinced by that argument, you can think in this way. The five seats are XXYYZ, we first consider the position for seat Z, it is $\binom{5}{1}$. Then select a number (from 8 numbers) to sit on this seat. There are 8 choices. Next, we left with four seats and 7 numbers, and we need to choose two numbers from 7, so it is $\binom{7}{2}$. Final step, arrange this two selected numbers on the four seats such as 2233, or 3322, 2323, 3232, 2332, 3223. Can you show, for any two fixed numbers, such as A and B, if we arrange them as above, there are 6 cases?

Comment: We have to choose 2 positions from 4 for the first number A. 4C2 = 6. @MathFail

Comment: If you have justify this step, then you multiply them together: $\binom{5}{1}\cdot 8\cdot\binom{7}{2}\cdot\color{red}6$ and this equals $\color{red}{\frac{1}2}\left[ \binom{5}{2}\cdot8\binom{3}{2}\cdot7\cdot6\right]$

Comment: By using a calculator I can see that they are equivalent. But I would never be able to make the inference that one is equal to the other! @MathFail. How did you make the jump? IS it just experience?

Comment: This is just to convince you actually these two counting methods are equivalent. 5 seats, no matter you did in your own method, "5 choose 2, then 3 choose 2", or you did in this way, "5 choose 1, then 4 choose 2", maybe you are more comfortable with the latter. But actually the latter also implicitly uses the symmetry and divide by 2. Because, by initial argument, when deal with the "4 choose 2" step, with two fixed number, say number 7 and number 8, first $\binom{4}2\cdot 2$, then $\binom{2}2\cdot 1$, multiply them and you get 12, but you know it should be 6, due to symmetry and divide by 2.